# Error on deleting any content

Tags: nodes

Whenever I try to delete any content, be it custom or core, I am unable to do so. I get the following error:

> warning:%20array_flip%28%29:%20Can%20only%20flip%20STRING%20and%20INTEGER%20values!%20in%20DrupalDefaultEntityController->load%28%29%20%28line%20178%20of%20/opt/lampp/htdocs/includes/entity.inc%29.
>
> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Message could not be
>   converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2139 of
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/includes/database/database.inc).

What is this, and how can I delete the content be it a basic page or article etc

Comment: Is the error really URL encoded? If not could you get the proper error and edit that in instead? You can also format code and errors so they're more easily identifiable. See [this post](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/is-there-a-better-way-to-indent-code-and-highlight-code-or-errors) for more details

Comment: yes it is url encoded..i have just copied and posted the error which i received